# Visual Studio 2019 .NET VB Web application how do i display a query result to a ViewGrid?

Tags: .net, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to the VB and the .NET framework. What I'm trying to do is for a user to input two values in textbox which will filter the query results. I made a separate class that manages the SQL functions and i use those functions for the query search for the different web forms. My current problem is that the GridView does not display or shows the query results when i click on the button where it performs the query search. I assign the values in to the ViewGrid following way 'GridView1.DataSource = dt'.

Am I missing a step, do i have to setup the ViewGrid or a datasource in a certain way?

For additional context in my page design i have two textbox, an execute button, and a default GridView.

I'll appreciate the help anyone can give me.

My Code:

**SQLControl** class:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class SQLControl

Private ReadOnly ConStr As String = "constring"
Private DBCmd As SqlCommand

'Query Parameters
Public Params As New List(Of SqlParameter)

'This generates a blank sqlclient class with the deafult connection string
Public Sub New()
End Sub

'Allow connection string override
Public Sub New(connectionString As String)
    ConStr = connectionString
End Sub

'Execute Query Sub
Public Function ExecQuery(query As String) As DataTable

    Dim DBDT = New DataTable
    Using DBCon As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            DBCmd As New SqlCommand(query, DBCon)
        Params.ForEach(Sub(p) DBCmd.Parameters.Add(p))
        Params.Clear()
        DBCon.Open()
        DBDT.Load(DBCmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return DBDT

End Function

'Add Params
Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)
    Dim NewParam As New SqlParameter(Name, Value)
    Params.Add(NewParam)
End Sub

End Class
```

Webform button code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Discount_Detail
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Private ReadOnly SQL As New SQLControl("constring")

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

Protected Sub ExecuteButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExecuteButton.Click
    Dim StoreID As Integer
    Dim TransID As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(StoreIDTextbox.Text, StoreID) Then
        MsgBox("Invalid input. Please enter both Store ID and Transaction ID.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Not Integer.TryParse(TransactionIDTextbox.Text, TransID) Then
        MsgBox("Invalid input. Please enter both Store ID and Transaction ID.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    SQL.AddParam("@Str_ID", StoreID)
    SQL.AddParam("@Tran_ID", TransID)
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Try
        dt = SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT H.Emp_ID, H.Cust_ID, D.* 
          FROM Transaction_Header H 
          INNER JOIN LN_Detail L On (H.Str_ID = L.Str_ID And H.Rgst_ID = L.Rgst_ID And H.Tran_ID = L.Tran_ID)
          INNER Join LN_Discount D ON (L.Str_ID = D.Str_ID AND L.Rgst_ID = D.Rgst_ID AND L.Tran_ID = D.Tran_ID AND L.Tran_LN_Num = D.Tran_LN_Num)
          WHERE H.Str_ID = @Str_ID AND H.Tran_ID = @Tran_ID")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    GridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what i was missing for the output of the query result on the ViewGrid.

At the end i was missing the GridView1.Databind()

```
GridView1.DataSource = dt
GridView1.DataBind()
```